# Showing a winline from a button array

Tags: c#, arrays, tic-tac-toe

I have a tic tac toe program with a re-sizable grid. I have a CheckXWinner( ) function that checks for a horizonal, vertical, and both diagonal winning combos in the grid. The win check works great but after a certain combo has won, I need to highlight those winning buttons by turning them a different color, I'd say IndiaRed, and preferably drawing a line through them. I'd be happy with at least getting them turned red though.

```
public void CheckXWinner(Button[] buttonArray)
{          
        int arrLength = buttonArray.Length; 
        int hCount = 0;
        int vCount = 0;
        int d1Count = 0;
        int d2Count = 0;
        int root = (int)Math.Sqrt(Convert.ToDouble(arrLength));  

        for (int i = 0;  i < root;  i++)
        {
            //Sets the counter for the winners back to zero
            d2Count = 0;
            d1Count = 0;
            hCount = 0;
            vCount = 0;
                for(int j = 0;  j < root; j++)
                {
                    //increments the appropriate counter if the button contains an X
                    if (buttonArray[ (i * root) + j ].Text == "X")
                        hCount++;

                    if (buttonArray[ j + (j * root)].Text == "X")
                        d1Count++;

                    if (buttonArray[(j * (root - 1)) + (root - 1)].Text == "X")
                        d2Count++;

                    if (buttonArray[ i + (root * j)].Text == "X")
                        vCount++;

                }
                //if the counter reaches the amount needed for a win, show win message
                if ( hCount == root )
                { 
                    MessageBox.Show("Horizontal winner found !");
                    break;
                }
                else if ( vCount == root )
                { 
                    MessageBox.Show("Virtical winner found !");
                    break;
                }
                else if ( d1Count == root )
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Diagonal winner found !");
                    break;
                }
                else if (d2Count == root)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Diagonal winner #2 found !");
                    break;
                }
        }//end of for loop
   }//end of CheckXWinner
```

Once I have a winning count reached, how can i then go back and change the .backcolor properties of those buttons to IndiaRed?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
    public void CheckXWinner(Button[] buttonArray)
    {          
        int arrLength = buttonArray.Length; 
        int root = (int)Math.Sqrt(Convert.ToDouble(arrLength));  

        for (int i = 0;  i < root;  i++)
        {
            //Sets the counter for the winners back to zero
            int d2Count = 0;
            int d1Count = 0;
            int hCount = 0;
            int vCount = 0;
                for(int j = 0;  j < root; j++)
                {
                    //increments the appropriate counter if the button contains an X
                    //Horizonal win
                    if (buttonArray[(i*root) + j].Text == "X")
                    {
                        hCount++;
                        if (hCount == root)
                        {
                            for (int z = (root - 1); z >= 0; z--)
                            {
                                buttonArray[(i*root) + z].BackColor = Color.IndianRed;
                            }
                            Xwins();
                        }
                    }//end of Horizonal win

                    //Left to right diagonal
                    if (buttonArray[j + (j*root)].Text == "X")
                    {
                        d1Count++;
                        if (d1Count == root)
                        {
                            for (int z = (root - 1); z >= 0; z--)
                            {
                                buttonArray[z + (z * root)].BackColor = Color.IndianRed;
                            }
                            Xwins();
                        }
                    }//end of LTR win

                    //Right to left diagonal
                    if (buttonArray[(j*(root - 1)) + (root - 1)].Text == "X")
                    {
                        d2Count++;
                        if (d2Count == root)
                        {
                            for (int z = (root - 1); z >= 0; z--)
                            {
                                buttonArray[(z*(root - 1)) + (root - 1)].BackColor = Color.IndianRed;
                            }
                            Xwins();
                        }
                    }//end of RTL win

                    //Vertical win
                    if (buttonArray[i + (root*j)].Text == "X")
                    {
                        vCount++;
                        if (vCount == root)
                        {
                            for (int z = (root - 1); z >= 0; z--)
                            {
                                buttonArray[i + (root*z)].BackColor = Color.IndianRed;
                            }
                            Xwins();
                        }
                    }//end of vert win

                }//end of for j loop
        }//end of for loop

    }//end of CheckXWinner
```